# API Automated Testing Tool XML & JSON

Tags: test-design, browser-automation, tools, web-application, test-strategy

I am looking for an automated test tool that can:

MUST HAVE:

1. Ability to connect to a server endpoint, that returns `JSON` or `XML` based data.
2. Ability to fully parse and validate either `XML` or `JSON` (both would be a plus).
3. Ability to traverse `XML` or `JSON` for `functional validation`.

NICE TO HAVE:

4. `Performance analysis tool` sets (mean, max, min, std deviation for result sets) — including thread execution setup.
5. Template based test cases.  Set up a test template and feed the template with a data set — if we have this (`jmeter` does).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of tools that can do everything you want.  Do you have a specific language/programming environment you prefer?

I prefer RestSharp and json.net if you've got visual studio and C#, however there's nothing built in to do the performance stuff unless you have visual studio ultimate in which case you can use the load testing tool. As for the last nice to have, you can do data driven tests using mstest or tools like nunit.

JMeter + either the json library from http://json.org/ or gson can do everything you want including the performance and data driven tests in a java environment.

Other popular tools:

- SoapUI
- TestMaker
- WebInject

Comment: SOAP response can be schema-validated against XSD in WSDL definition. JSON response is validated against what? Are there schemas for JSON services? Or you mean another type of validation?

Comment: Yes, json.net for example uses the json schema defined at http://json-schema.org/.  You can create json schema files and use the JsonValidatingDeserializer for all of the responses.  Examples here: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/01/04/json-net-3-5-beta-2-json-schema-validation.aspx

Comment: It looks like for java this json schema validator tool https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator uses the same schema defined at json-schema.org

Answer (score 0):

Check out the latest release of CAM editor v3.0 and the CAMV validation engine.  I believe we are covering all these bases for you.

There are instructional videos on YouTube for working with JSON and then creating test suites with CAMV.

Also the CAMV engine is very flexible in its deployment options and ability to call it and return validation results.

See http://www.cameditor.org for more details and the Sourceforge project site.

Comment: @user8419242, I guess you are the author of CAM editor?

Comment: Hi @user841942, based on your comment it looks like you're involved in the CAM editor project - it's good manners to explicitly call out your relationship with the company when you refer people to it. Please update your answer to state your relationship to the CAM editor project.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of such tools available, you might try [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [HttpMaster](http://www.httpmaster.net), I guess both support XML/JSON handling and validation.
For more than a basic performance analysis, you will have to look elsewhere, JMeter would be a good choice (as you have already mentioned).